# How do I remove opcodes using hexcurse?

Tags: binary-files, hex-editor

I am trying to do some Hex editing using hexcurse on Linux. The following is the link to the binary file I am editing. How do I remove all of the text that isn't highlighted in white?

[The image of the binary file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58OuF.png)
[image]

Comment: Oh my. What exactly did you do to get the output shown in the screenshot?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I was attempting to follow a book to write a bootsector, and I was using vim as my hex editor, and on vim, only the highlighted numbers were shown. When opening it with a real text editor, well, that showed up.